# Java background image on object. Can't find my public variable

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent

What i want is that everytime a cell is considered "Dead", this image

http://preview.turbosquid.com/Preview/Content_2009_07_25__02_34_32/dead%20cell%201.jpg8c11d904-1879-4bd9-b31c-439bcbb83646Larger.jpg

shows on the background of the object.

I have a class called "Game" in the package p_game with the following code

```
public class Game{
    public Image bg_image;
    public Game(){
           //Here is code that creates a 17*17 table of cells with the status 'Dead' 
        this.Cellules= new p_cell.Cellule[17][17];  
        for (int i=1; i<17; i++){
           for (int j=1; j<17; j++){
               Cellules[i][j]=new p_cell.Cellule(i,j,"Dead");
           }
        }
           //Here is code for the URL and Image
           URL url;
           try {
               url = new URL("http://preview.turbosquid.com/Preview/Content_2009_07_25__02_34_32/dead%20cell%201.jpg8c11d904-1879-4bd9-b31c-439bcbb83646Larger.jpg");
               bg_image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);
           } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }
­}
```

I am trying to use bg_image in my class Cell (in the package p_cell) but it says the variable doesn't exist. What am i missing here?

```
public class Cell{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        g.drawImage(bg_image, 0, 0);

    } 
}
```

Error given: bg_image cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: `bg_image` is an instance field in `Game`, not in `Cell`.

Comment: but isn't public suppose to make it available to every package and class?

Comment: It's public but it's not an instance of `Cell`. If you've to access it, use `Game.bg_image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every variable belongs to a class or class instance.

To use bg_image you must instantiate `Game` class like this: `Game game = new Game();`, and then use it with instance reference: `game.bg_image`.
If you don't want to have instance of `Game` class, you should make `bg_image` static and use it like this: `Game.bg_image`.
Additional reading: 
about static variables: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html 
about instance variables: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Comment: I made bg_image static and accessed it by game.bg_image and everything worked like a charm; thank you!